# BLE how to set uuid to 16bit

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an app that advertises data over BLE.
I am creating a ParcelUuid from a 128-bit UUID like this

```
pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("128-bit UUID)
```

And I am adding it to AdvertiseData like this

```
aData = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                        .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                        .addServiceData(pUuid, data.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
                        .build();
```

Now what is happening is that Sometimes it comes like a 16-bit UUID in the packet and sometimes as a 128-bit UUID.

How can I set it to only come as a 16-bit UUID always???

Answer (score 13):

If you want to declare a 16-bit UUID, you have to use a base-uuid, which is fixed:

```
0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

e.g.

```
ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("00001234-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

The BLE standard recognizes this UUID as a 16 bit one.

You can read more about 16 bit UUIDs [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery)

Comment: If I understand correctly (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) "1234" is considered to be just just 16bit (2 bytes == 4 nibbles) because each digit is treated as a nibble (4bits) right? So "DE03" => 0xDE (<-first byte) 0x03 (<-second byte)  And this is why it's considered to be 16bits. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Hex representations of bytes usually consist of two digits. :)